# How to check an array for specific value in jquery? (chessboard.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, chess, chessboard.js

I am trying to make a game where the aim is to correctly set up the chessboard using `chessboard.js`

I have this at the moment which shows the start position as an object, and the most recent move in the same format:

```
var setup1 = ChessBoard.fenToObj('rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR');
var onDrop = function(source, target, piece, newPos, oldPos, orientation) {

$.each( setup1, function( key, value ) {
if (target == key && piece !== value) {
console.log("wrong");
return 'snapback';
}

});
```

Setup1 here returns Object `{a8: "bR", b8: "bN", c8: "bB", d8: "bQ", e8: "bK"…}`

target returns a8 
piece returns "bR"

What would be the best way to check that **setup1 contains** the correct combination of  **target** and **piece**?

When I try the above, I can correctly display "wrong" in the console, but cannot return 'snapback' to onDrop. Is there a problem with nested functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`setup1.contains(move1);`**

Comment: When I try that it returns: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'contains'. I get the same error if I try indexOf.

Comment: Well, so try to create a loop and check one by one.

Comment: I have edited the question with an update, it seems this partially works, but I cannot return 'snapback', this might be a different problem, but if the loop is not there, then 'snapback' works?

Comment: Should work and return 'snapback'. What is returning?

Comment: It is not returning anything to the console other than "wrong" from the previous line and the piece does not snapback. If the entire $.each loop is replaced with "return 'snapback';" then it works for all moves.